# SQL server set variable equal to result from concatenated string

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I want to verify a row is deleted. I am passing both the table name and the value in question to my stored procedure. it deletes said items but I thought I would verify it was actually deleted. so I created @ItemFound and want to let it equal to the count. But it is not getting set since its inside of the SQL string I'm building.
How do I create a SQL string, Execute it, set that result to a variable, then check the variable later?

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
(@UPCode varchar(20),
@Tablename varchar(200))

AS
Declare @SQLString varchar(1000)
Select @SQLString = ('Delete from ' + @Tablename + ' Where [UPCode] = ''' + @UPCode  + '''')
print @SQLString
--[My Table name]
EXEC(@SQLString)
-- area of issue where
Declare @ItemFound as int
Declare @SQLString2 varchar(500)
-- this gave error @ItemFound not declared so I added it to the string I'm building. but its not available outside.
Select @SQLString2 = ('Declare @ItemFound as int; set @ItemFound = (Select count(*) from  ' + @Tablename + ' Where UPCode = ''' + @UPCode  + ''')')
print @SQLString2
EXEC(@SQLString2)
-- @ItemFound is not equal to zero so it returns 'Item NOT Deleted'
If @ItemFound = 0
    Begin
        Select 'Item Deleted'
    End
else
    Begin
        Select 'Item NOT Deleted'
    End
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would use [@@ROWCOUNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [EXISTS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this. It's the most common and applicable approach. Also, if I pass `someTable; DELETE * FROM someTable; --` into the `@TableName` parameter guess what would happen? That's right, you have a SQL Injection flaw in your code. You should use [QUOTENAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) at least

Comment: If you can't trust SQL Server to do deletes, you either have some very fruity triggers defined or you're overly paranoid

Comment: `someTable where 1=1; --` would be a better example

Answer (score 1):

just revert your execution order: Execute @SQLString2 before @SQLString

```
Create Procedure MyProcedure
(@UPCode varchar(20),
@Tablename varchar(200))

AS
Declare @SQLString2 varchar(500)
-- this gave error @ItemFound not declared so I added it to the string I'm building. but its not available outside.
Select @SQLString2 = ('Declare @ItemFound as int; set @ItemFound = (Select count(*) from  ' + @Tablename + ' Where UPCode = ''' + @UPCode  + ''')')
print @SQLString2
EXEC(@SQLString2)

Declare @SQLString varchar(1000)
Select @SQLString = ('Delete from ' + @Tablename + ' Where [UPCode] = ''' + @UPCode  + '''')
print @SQLString
--[My Table name]
EXEC(@SQLString)
-- area of issue where
Declare @ItemFound as int


-- @ItemFound is not equal to zero so it returns 'Item NOT Deleted'
If @ItemFound = 0
    Begin
        Select 'Item Deleted'
    End
else
    Begin
        Select 'Item NOT Deleted'
    End
```

Another solution may be using `OUTPUT` in your delete statement:
[More infos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)